# Oracle 10.2.0.5 : sometimes found object invalid by itself

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Sometimes I encountered an object invalid by itself without anyone alters anything on the associated objects on the Oracle 10.2.0.5.

Would anyone recommend what I could do?

PS: I already check the alert log and the trace file but have not found anything that relates to the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Objects do not uncompile themselves. So regardless of what you say, some dependency of the object has been touched. It might be as simple as somebody triggering a recompilation of a PL/SQL unit, without actually *changing* anything.

Comment: Oracle does this automatically when - as mentioned - related or dependent objects are touched in some way, and will revalidate such objects automatically the next time they are used. There is nothing for you to do.

Comment: @pmdba, "There is nothing for you to do".  Well, as far as the OP's question.  On the other hand, seeing as the OP is running the seriously out of date and out of support version 10, there is plenty for him to do in other areas ... :-)

Comment: Fundamental concepts do not change frequently @EdStevens, so you may of course write a package that invalidates itselfs by droping a table that it uses.